# How to replace a string pattern with increasing integers using regex

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have multiple .xml files in which I have a repeating string pattern. I want to replace each instance of that pattern with an integer starting with "1".

e.g.

Input:

```
APPLE is my favorite fruit. APPLE is red in color.
```

Expected Output:

```
1 is my favorite fruit. 2 is red in color.
```

Comment: Only possible with some programming language (which you did not specify).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simple incrementing integers from 1, 2, 3, ... (or 0, 1, 2, ...) you can use the new snippet variables `$CURSOR_NUMBER` or `$CURSOR_INDEX` respectively.

You would still have to find a way to select all the find matches you want to replace (and so I think the extension below is better).  You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to progressively select the occurrences you want or using the Find Widget:

Find: `APPLE`

and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select **all** matches and then insert a snippet like:

```
"Increment integer": {
    "prefix": "i++",
    "body": [
        "${CURSOR_NUMBER}",
    ]
},
```

by typing its trigger prefix `i++` and voila, all the `APPLE` instances are replaced by increasing integers.

---

I am sure there are other extensions that can do this, but using one that I wrote this is very easy: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).

Create this keybinding (in your keybindings.json):

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    // "find": "APPLE",            // actually not necessary
    "replace": "${matchNumber}",
    "matchCase": true              // match only APPLE, not Apple
  }
}
```

That will replace whatever word your cursor is on with the `matchNumber` starting at 1.  If you wanted to start at 0, use `${matchIndex}`.

If you need to specify a more complicated regex find, you can do that too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen) you can do this.

- select all the `APPLE` instances you want, any way you like, `Ctrl+D`, `Selet All Occurrences`, `Alt+Enter` from Find dialog
- execute command **Generate Text  based on regular expression**
- as match expression use: `.*`
- as generator expression use: `{{=i+1}}`