# VSCode: Incremented numbers at each cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you create multiple cursors in VSCode, how can you type a number at each cursor such that each number is 1 greater than the previous number, starting at 0?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859077/836330 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/69943876/836330