# how to put increased number for multiline selection in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to add increased number for multi selected caret in visual studio code.
now, When I type it write same words.

[image]

But I would like to add increased number by some shortkey so that I don't need to update each one manually.
Preferred result should be like this.

[image]

I want to know if this is possible in vs code.

Thanks

Comment: IMO, Mark's [snippet-based solution to this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859077/1329892) is more straightforward than the current answers for this task.

Answer (score 8):

You do not need an extension for your use case, although that may make it easier.  Here is how to do it without an extension.

1. Find: `(?<=index:\s*)\d+`  : this selects only the digits following `index:` .
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will select all those digits.

Now you can run a simple snippet to replace those digits with an increasing number that could be 0-based or 1-based.  Make this keybinding to insert the snippet (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",        // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "$CURSOR_NUMBER"  // this will increment and is 1-based
  }
}
```

3. Trigger the above keybinding.  Demo:

[image: demo of incrementing a digit with a snippet]

---

Here is an extension approach, using an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), that makes this easy.  Make this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",        // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(?<=index:\\s*)\\d+",   // same find regex
    "replace": "${matchNumber}",     // this variable will increase, 1-based
    "isRegex": true
  }
}
```

That combines the find and replace in one step.

[image: increment digit with Find and Transform extension]

---

Here is another method so you do not need to hardcode the starting point.

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": [
      "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch", 
      "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
    ],
    "find": "(?<=index:\\s*)\\d+",
    "replace": [
      "$${",
        // whatever math you want to do here
        "return Number(${CLIPBOARD}) + ${matchIndex};",
      "}$$",
    ],
    "isRegex": true,
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  }
}
```

Put the cursor next to or select the number you want as the starting point.  The number could be anywhere in the document actually.

[image: sequence from selection demo]

Comment: Is there any method to change base number? so It start from any number (I don't want this number to be written in some file, but want to be dynamic by my input), like 4,5,6... instead of 1,2,3, Thanks

Comment: @NomuraNori Yes, I'll show an example of that.  With the extension you can do math, so you can start with any base (or no base) and manipulate as you like.

Comment: @NomuraNori I need a little more explanation.  What do you mean "to be dynamic by my input), like 4,5,6... instead of 1,2,3"?

Comment: I mean I want to set any start number, I don't want it set in any file statically

Comment: @NomuraNori I added an easy way to use any number from the document as the starting point for a sequence.

Comment: I encounter this error when I try : `command 'findInCurrentFile' not found`

Comment: @BJam I assume you installed the extension?  If so, please file an issue with the details of your setting or keybinding you tried.  Thank you.

Comment: Ok sorry it works after installing extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview). Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Increment Selection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albymor.increment-selection) or [Text Pastry](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jkjustjoshing.vscode-text-pastry)